# pattern matching and dealing with data in expect?

Tags: sed, awk, expect, cisco

contents of `expect_out(buffer)`

```
GigabitEthernet1/0/9   unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
GigabitEthernet1/0/10  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/0/11  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/0/23  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/0/24  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/1/1   unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/1/2   unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/1/3   unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/1/4   unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Te1/1/1                unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Te1/1/2                unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet2/0/1      unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet2/0/2      unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet2/0/24     unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet2/0/1   unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
GigabitEthernet2/0/2   unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
```

I have the foloowing data above and i need to count the number of data for each type
so that i can have the info like :

```
GigabitEthernet1 : 20
GigabitEthernet2 : 20
Tel             : 2
FastEthernet2    : 4
FastEthernet1    : 4
```

total   : 50

How can I do it?
Any help would be appreciated because I don't know in which direction to proceed because I am a novice as far as expect/tcl is concerned.

I tried to use split function to parse it by using newline as delimiter so that I can use regex inside for loop but it seems that because $expect_output(buffer) is a variable it might not have any lines in it.

Moreover can I use awk or sed inside expect then it would be not so difficult I guess. But an expected solution would be standard.

Comment: why `GigabitEthernet2 : 20`? I only see two of them in your input.

Comment: sorry the data was big so i took it out i just gave that as an example

Answer (score 2):

based on your current input data, this one-liner:

```
 awk -F'/' '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x" : "a[x];t+=a[x];}print "total : "t}' file
```

gives:

```
FastEthernet2 : 3
GigabitEthernet1 : 9
GigabitEthernet2 : 2
Te1 : 2
total : 16
```

Comment: thanks,@Kent but still i am hoping that someone would guide me in doing that using expect beacuse my complete code is in expect but if could use that in expect script somehow it would be great :-).I mean I may have to set it(expect_out(buffer)) as as environment variable then and use awk to to do this kind of processing

Answer (score 1):

Since Expect is based on **Tcl/TK** you should familiarize yourself with that language since it contains numerous string handling options. Here is some code which hopefully sets you on the right track.

```
set str $expect_out(buffer)
# Strip everything after slash
regsub -all -line "/.*" $str "" str2

puts $str2    # just to see what you got so far

# Convert string into list
set li [split $str2 "\n"]

# Convert list into array
# This is actually the tricky part which converts the list into an
# associative array whose entries have first to be set to one
# and later have to be increased by one
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $li]} {incr i} {
  if { [info exists arr([lindex $li $i]) ] } {
    incr arr([lindex $li $i])   } {
    set  arr([lindex $li $i]) 1 }
}

# Now get the statistics
array get arr

# will print this for your example
#  GigabitEthernet2 2 Te1 2 FastEthernet2 3 GigabitEthernet1 9
```

And you should tag this question with Tcl and TK too.